# About No such file or directory compilation terminated error

Tags: c++, network-programming, include-path

I'm new to C++ , i have installed the [lib Com++](http://www.cplusplusworld.com/socketlibrary.html) for network programming 
but when i just include the header file

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ComPP/ComPlusPlus>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc ,char *argv[]){

    cout << "Hello World" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

i get the error

```
main.cpp:2:29: fatal error: ComPP/ComPlusPlus: No such file or directory
```

using fedora linux
i used this command to compile as mentioned in the manual

```
g++ -I ./ -L./ -o server  main.cpp -lCommPP -lsys -lpthread -lrt
```

the directory /usr/include/ComPP/  is exist with all the header files

```
ComPP
├── ComPlusPlus
│   ├── AClnt.h
│   ├── ASrvContext.h
│   ├── ASrv.h
│   ├── ASrvProperties.h
│   ├── Clone.h
│   ├── Comm.h
│   ├── ComPlusPlus
│   ├── Context.h
│   ├── Daemon.h
│   ├── Directory.h
│   ├── DirEntry.h
│   ├── File.h
│   ├── Launch.h
│   ├── Mutex.h
│   ├── Poll.h
│   ├── Process.h
│   ├── SClnt.h
│   ├── Sem.h
│   ├── ShMem.h
│   ├── Signalling.h
│   ├── Socket.h
│   ├── SocketTcp.h
│   ├── SocketUdp.h
│   ├── SocketUnix.h
│   ├── SrvProperties.h
│   ├── SSrvContext.h
│   ├── SSrv.h
│   ├── SSrvProperties.h
│   └── Thread.h
└── SysPlusPlus
    ├── ComException.h
    ├── config.h
    ├── GenCfg.h
    ├── Logger.h
    ├── syscall.h
    ├── syslib.h
    ├── SysPlusPlus
    └── Tools.h
```

Comment: You are not specifying which of the header-files that you want to include.

Answer (score 2):

You do not include a header file. `#include <ComPP/ComPlusPlus>` this is a directory. From what you posted you need to add another ComPlusPlus. `#include <ComPP/ComPlusPlus/ComPlusPlus>` but it very uncommon to use headers without the .h ending. So you better check the spelling of directories and files.

After carefully reading the cplusplus.com site. The error is indeed something else.
They assume that you set the include path of your compiler to ComPP. E.g as Ahmed already commented with a -I /usr/include/ComPP.
So you can either fully qualify your include in the cpp file as /usr/include/ is a standard search path for gcc or you add another path.
Nevertheless I find it very irritating to use a header without a .h ending.

Comment: i just following the example http://www.cplusplusworld.com/ExampleClient.cpp.html

Comment: when i use the option  -I /usr/include/ComPP everything goes fine as the example ,i think

Comment: That is another way to do it. If you add ComPP to your search path the include statement denotes to a file again.

Comment: Quite a few libraries and the c++ std library do use header files with the ".h" suffix.

Comment: That is quite true and from the standard it is possible to name a header with or without .h. But still I think it is quite a common practice to end headers .h. And personally I found it a bad Idea from the standardization group to drop the .h ending but I don't want to start a flame war about the pro and cons of this decision.

Answer (score 0):

When you download the comPP library there is a ProgrammersGuide.pdf in the Documentation folder. There you can find what libs are needed. The file is not 100% accurate. I got it working using this format:

```
g++ -I/usr/include/ComPP -lComPP -lSysPP -lpthread -lrt ExampleClient.cpp -o ExampleClient
```

This will only work if you have these includes:

```
#include <SysPlusPlus/SysPlusPlus>
#include <ComPlusPlus/ComPlusPlus>
```

Kind Regards,

Maarten